# Fetch URI segment value - The angular way?

Tags: angularjs

I have this crud URL format:

> domain.com/config/someconfig/edit/2

Where I open the form ready to be prepped with the contents from record of id 2.

**How**, can I just get the 2 from the URI?

The easiest way possible would be something like:

```
if($location._uriseg(4) && typeof $location._uriseg(4) === 'number') then...
```

Is angular.js missing something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Created a filter for angular to have that method (_uriseg) available:

```
app.filter('_uriseg', function($location) {
  return function(segment) {
    // Get URI and remove the domain base url global var
    var query = $location.absUrl().replace(BASE_URL,"");
    // To obj
    var data = query.split("/");    
    // Return segment *segments are 1,2,3 keys are 0,1,2
    if(data[segment-1]) {
      return data[segment-1];
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Now I'm able to call:

```
$scope.email = $filter('_uriseg')(3);
```

So using this filter one can fetch the value of any URL segment.

I still believe angular.js to have something similar, if anyone care to share the default method, thanks.

---

I have also created another filter to help codeigniter fellows out there, to get controller actions from the URI, codeigniter style:

```
app.filter('getCImr', function($location) {
  return function(controller) {
    // Get URI and remove the domain base url global var
    var query = $location.absUrl().replace(BASE_URL,"");
    // To obj
    var data = query.split("/");
    // Remove CI controller
    delete data[0];    
    var result = {};
    // Map action and record ID/Whatever
    result[data[1]] = data[2];
    return result;
  }
});
```

So let's say your codeigniter URI is something like:

> domain.com/controller/function/id

You can do a:

```
$scope.id = $filter('getCImr')('controller')['function'];
```

To get:

```
console.log($scope.id); // id
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

is this an angular route set up via $routeProvider.when? if so, you can use $routeParams to grab the value. something like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/thing/:thingId', {
    templateUrl: 'thing.html',
    controller: ThingCntl
});
```

then in your controller, you can used $routeParams.thingId to access the value

Comment: It's not setup as an angular route. It's just a simple page, and I'm trying to work with that url to get record ids, as the entire website is coded in codeigniter and that's the way url's work in there.

Answer (score 0):

My version the codeigniter way..

```
angular.module('myApp.Filters', [])
.filter('uri', function($location) {
    return {
        segment: function(segment) {
            var data = $location.path().split("/");
            if(data[segment-1]) { return data[segment-1]; }
            return false;
        },
        total_segments: function() {
            var data = $location.path().split("/");
            var i = 0;
            angular.forEach(data, function(value){
            if(value.length) { i++; }
            });
            return i;
        }
    };
});

//GET URI SEGMENT
$filter('uri').segment(0)
//GET SEGMENT LENGTH
$filter('uri').total_segments()
```